# Проверка типа аудио файлов

Tags: php

Каким образом можно проверить тип файлов при загрузке на сервер?

Интересуют такие: **mp3, ogg, aac**.

Не просто `$_FILES['audio']['type']`, а именно через какую либо утилиту, например.

Проверка изображений, например, делается вот так — `getimagesize($image)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[media-info](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7788-PHP-Retrieve-the-details-of-video-files-with-mediainfo.html)

> This class retrieve the details of video files with mediainfo.
> It executes the mediainfo program to analyze a video file and parses the program output to extract the video file details.
> Currently it can get the video length, video width and height, image aspect ratio and file length.
> Это для видеофайлов.

---

Другое решение:
[GetID3](http://www.getid3.org/)
Поддерживает кучу аудио/видео форматов, позволяет изменять информацию.

Comment: Уже установил `mediainfo`.

Answer (score 2):

Найти описания интересующих форматов, вернее, только их заголовков. Например, [mp3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure), [ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#File_format). И проверять у загруженных файлов первые несколько байт, чтобы определить/удостовериться в верности определения формата.

AAC - подраздел MPEG-4, поэтому ищите описание файлового формата для mp4.